# Как программно заставить появиться клавиатуру?

Tags: java, android, клавиатура

Я хочу заставить появиться клавиатуру устройства, когда фокус не стоит в текстовом поле и т.д. И самой программно обрабатывать события от клавиатуры. Как её программно можно открыть? И можно ли программно закрыть клавиатуру?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте примерно такой код:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(view, flags);
```

На самом деле у меня эта штука не особо работала (пробуйте), а вот спрятать получалось:)
Можно извратиться и послать событие нажатия на клавишу, фокус не помогает. Проверял.

Comment: Проверила, выяснилось, что открывать клавиатуру нужно так:

    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);

А прятать так:

    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);